# How to stop a dropdown Filter Menu closing on click

Tags: javascript

I am creating a filtered table where the user can select the options using checkboxes but no matter what I try when I click on the checkbox the menu closes. PLEASE HELP!

Codepen
https://codepen.io/j-k-a-w/pen/gOXKOaZ

```
<div class="sub-option-right filter-search block-sizing">
  <div class="select-filter">
    <button type="button" class="collapse control main-collapse">
      Filter
    </button>
    <div class="content main-content">
      <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
        By type
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="checker">
          <label class="container">Type One
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checker">
          <label class="container">Type Two
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
        By supplier
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="checker">
          <label class="container">Supplier One
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">Supplier Two
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
          By unit type
        </button>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">gsms
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">mtrs
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">pcs
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
          By currency
        </button>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">EUR €
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">GBP £
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">USD $
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-filter">
      <button type="button" class="collapse control main-collapse">
        Sort
      </button>
      <div class="content main-content">
        <div class="sort-options">
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">#id
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">Article reference
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">Item name
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button id="sort-btn-acc" type="button" class="sort-btn">
          Accending
        </button>
        <button id="sort-btn-desc" type="button" class="sort-btn">
          Descending
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Below is the Javascript that controls the checkbox dropdown filters.**

```
const coll = document.querySelectorAll(".collapse");

let iCount;
for (iCount = 0; iCount < coll.length; iCount++) {
  coll[iCount].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("control-arrow-active");
    let content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
const subFilters = document.querySelectorAll(".main-content");

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it {
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.matches(".collapse")) {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < subFilters.length; i++) {
      let openFilters = subFilters[i];
      let parent = subFilters[i].previousElementSibling;
      if (openFilters.style.display === "block") {
        parent.classList.toggle("active");
        parent.classList.toggle("control-arrow-active");
        openFilters.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Forgive me if I have formatted this incorrectly. I am new to this!**

Comment: Your problem is the css-selector to "click outside" of the menu is incorrect.  You are checking if you click any element not of class `.collapse` and that does not account for sub-elements.  So it then triggers your code to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out and, as there are many questions regarding this issue, I am posting my solution. It may not be the most elegant but it is at the limit of my understanding.

The comment by Joey is indeed correct, so I gave each filter unique identifiers : id="filterBy" & id="sortBy" and the same for the content to hide on outside click : id="filter-main-content" & id="sort-main-content"

```
<div class="sub-option-right filter-search block-sizing">
  <div id="filterBy" class="select-filter">
    <button type="button" class="collapse control main-collapse">
      Filter
    </button>
    <div id="filter-main-content" class="content main-content">
      <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
        By type
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="checker">
          <label class="container">Type One
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checker">
          <label class="container">Type Two
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
        By supplier
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="checker">
          <label class="container">Supplier One
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">Supplier Two
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
          By unit type
        </button>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">gsms
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">mtrs
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="collapse control sub-collapse">
          By currency
        </button>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">EUR €
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">GBP £
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sortBy" class="select-filter">
      <button type="button" class="collapse control main-collapse">
        Sort
      </button>
      <div id="sort-main-content" class="content main-content">
        <div class="sort-options">
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">#id
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="checker">
            <label class="container">Article reference
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button id="sort-btn-acc" type="button" class="sort-btn">
          Accending
        </button>
        <button id="sort-btn-desc" type="button" class="sort-btn">
          Descending
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then in javascript I created a function containing the eventListner and passed it two parameters; being variables for the new id's I set up. Now each filter response independently and their interior elements can be selected without the menu closing on click.

```
const filterBy = document.querySelector("#filterBy");
const subFilter = document.querySelector("#filter-main-content");
const sortBy = document.querySelector("#sortBy");
const subSort = document.querySelector("#sort-main-content");

const filterOptions = (fElmnt, subElmnt) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (fElmnt !== event.target && !fElmnt.contains(event.target)) {
      let parent = subElmnt.previousElementSibling;
      if (subElmnt.style.display === "block") {
        parent.classList.toggle("active");
        parent.classList.toggle("control-arrow-active");
        subElmnt.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
};

filterOptions(filterBy, subFilter);
filterOptions(sortBy, subSort);
```